# How to output facebook graph api story_tags data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm accessing facebook posts JSON data like this from facebook graph api:

```
    "data": [
    {
      "name": "Webdesigner Depot",
      "status_type": "shared_story",
      "story_tags": [
        {
          "id": "145830968342431",
          "name": "MyPage",
          "type": "page",
          "offset": 0,
          "length": 12
        },
        {
          "id": "185486171450",
          "name": "Webdesigner Depot",
          "type": "page",
          "offset": 20,
          "length": 17
        }
      ],
      "id": "1458309134468342_1696820887283831"
    }
  ]
```

I can output data like this:

```
$.each( posts.data, function( i, data ) {

  console.log(data.status_type);

});
```

But how can I output the story_tags data when the offset is unknown?

For example, how do I output data.story_tags.name and data.story_tags.id

Looping through story_tags doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `story_tags` is an array, so you need to loop over it. And then you just access the properties of the current item inside the loop ... It is actually exactly the same thing you are doing right now already - you are looping over the `data` property, and then access the `status_type`. The offset has absolutely nothing to do with it - it is just a property, no different than any of the others.

Comment: It is actually exactly the same thing you are doing right now already - you are looping over the `data` property, and then access the `status_type`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to loop over story_tags. All I get is 'undefined' or [object Object]

Comment: this is what I have put inside the first $.each statement: if (typeof data.story_tags !== 'undefined') {
          $.each( data.story_tags, function( j ) {
            console.log(this.status_type);
          });
        }

Comment: and that returns 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely `this` is not what you think it is. Just do it the same way as with the first loop - pass the element into the callback function as a second parameter, and then use that name to access the current item.

Comment: Still getting 'undefined' with: $.each( data.story_tags, function( j, param ) {
            console.log(param.name);
          });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140085/discussion-between-iamfredrik-and-cbroe).